# Context-sensitive GridLookUpEdit

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress's GridLookUpEdit control in a grid and I want the contents of the pop-up grid to change depending on some other values in the row that is being edited.

I thought that I could use the advBandedGridView1_ShowingEditor event handler to change the DataView for the GridLookupEdit, but I can't figure out how to get the values in the current row in that handler.  e.RowHandle is not available, so I can't use view.GetDataRow(e.RowHandle).

Firstly - is this handler this best place set the context-sensitive contents of the GridLookupEdit?

Second - how can I get the current row's data from this handler?

tia -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the view.GetDataRow(view.FocusedRowHandle) to determine the DataRow object corresponding to the row being edited.  Also, I would suggest that you use the GridView's ShownEditor event and set the properties of the gridView.ActiveEditor object.  I think that the [How to filter a second LookUp column based on a first LookUp column's value](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/A237.aspx) article should be helpful to you.

Comment: OK - that example looks excellent - I have one small problem with it: I am using a GridLookUpEdit instead of a LookupEdit.  At the line "DataTable table = edit.Properties.LookUpData.DataSource as DataTable;" I cannot use .LookUpData because it is not defined for GridLookUpEdit.  I have looked around the intellisense, but can't find a way to get the datasource for a GridLookUpEdit.

Comment: Bah - nevermind.  It's at edit.Properties.DataSource.  How did I miss that??